# Is it OK to edit someone else's question or answer when the choice of accepted answer otherwise contradicts the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div). It was asked and answered a number of years ago. The gist of it is that the question asks

> Is it possible to do this in CSS?

and the accepted answer says

> Here is a jQuery solution

while a number of other answers say

> No, it's not possible to do this in CSS, but here is a jQuery solution

or even

> Actually, you can work around this using CSS

The accepted answer has been heavily downvoted (30 downvotes and counting) because it is seen as skirting the question altogether, but the asker never explains in a comment or edit to reflect why they accepted that particular answer in spite of this apparent conflict. Not only that, but the asker made a few edits and comments to the question and the other answers, yet none of these actions attempted to clarify this either. In fact, if anything, their comment on one of the answers seems to further cement the original point of the question.

At this point, any of the following actions would have resolved this conflict (and stopped the downvotes) quite easily:

- **The asker chooses a different answer that actually addresses the question somehow.** This would also give the answerer a chance to delete their answer if they didn't want to deal with the downvotes, but I have a sneaking suspicion that the downvotes were *because* it was accepted in the first place...
- **The asker edits their question to reflect the choice of accepted answer.** Something as simple as "If it's not possible, jQuery is an option." and/or a retag would have sufficed.
- **The answerer edits their answer so it actually answers the question.** This would have been pretty trivial to do as well.

But instead, shortly after the answer was accepted, the answerer added the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag (and later [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) <del>[css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors)</del>) to the question, presumably on behalf of the asker based on their acceptance. I rolled it back on grounds that you shouldn't change a question to suit your answer. Someone else even pointed this out in a comment, and for all we know some of the downvotes could have been cast for this reason alone.

But at this point, given the large number of downvotes it has received, does it matter anymore *who* edits the question or answer, since neither will the asker nor the answerer do what they're in the best position to do based on the accept mark? Is there any recourse left for the accepted answer since, realistically, the downvotes won't be retracted even after it's been edited to satisfaction, and it'll take at least another 15 upvotes just to bring it back to the surface?

Note that by the time I rolled it back, it was several years after the question was first asked and the answer was already pretty badly downvoted in spite of the edit, and the asker has not attempted to dispute the edit, or participated in the question in any way ever since. Also, at some point in time, the question was automatically converted to a wiki because it was edited by many users, but I don't know if the retag was made before or after the conversion. I removed the wiki on the assumption that the asker never intended for it to be a wiki in the first place. And I only post this now because I happened to revisit the question after it was linked elsewhere today.

Comment: Seems like the OP endorsed the addition of [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] by accepting a jquery answer. That said, most people come here looking for a solution... not necessarily for an answer to their question exactly as it was framed. That answer got the OP where he needed to go... but it certainly wasn't a CSS solution to a specifically CSS question. So, I don't know...

Comment: But the question is in the black as you get more for an up vote than down vote

Comment: @Blam: But not everything is about rep.

Comment: I cast delete vote so this particular answer have chance to disappear... Also if that answer is marked as Wiki I'd prefer just editing it in shape by merging other answers (as essentially all are the same).

Comment: Bear in mind that the original question was not necessarily about CSS. It was about CSS _selectors_ which are indeed very prevalent in jQuery. OP may well have been looking for a selector to use in jQuery and just didn't come right out and say it. Your paraphrasing of the question is inaccurate. The question does not boil down to "Is this possible to do in CSS?"

Comment: @JLRishe: The OP responded to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275098/a-css-selector-to-get-last-visible-div/5275173#5275173) mentioning the CSS standard (and yet did not accept it for some reason), which is what led me to believe they were indeed hoping for a standards-based solution. I'm just going to go out on a limb and assume that they accepted the other answer because it provided a solution, whereas the one I link to originally did not.

Answer (score 27):

This is the way I read that Q+A:

> Q: I want to use a bottle to pound a nail.  I don't think that's going to work, can I use it anyway?
>
> A1: Here, use my hammer, it will work better.
>
> A2: You can't use a bottle, it will shatter.

31 SO users thought that A1 was unhelpful.  That's ... bizarre.  The answerer hasn't lent his hammer to anyone for the past 3 years, small wonder.

The only way I can think of rescuing that Q+A is to edit the question to emphasize that the OP was well aware that using a bottle was a bad idea.

Comment: I read it as more like: A1: "Use this hammer." A2: "A bottle will shatter, but you could use a hammer instead." Sure, A1 *provides* the hammer (unlike A2), but they don't say why they are giving a hammer when a bottle was asked for - or even, for that matter, acknowledge that Q asked for a bottle.

Comment: Answers should be strict and should help many people, not only one. If there is no tag `iron` than hammer cannot be a correct answer, but it may be a useful comment.

Comment: I would paraphrase the exchange as: __Q__: "I need a particular type of nail, but I won't tell you what I'm going to use it for." __A1__: "Here, use this hammer with this nail." __Q__: "Ok, thanks!" __Downvoters__: "How dare you give Q a hammer?!? Q didn't ask for a hammer!!!"

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the tag edits were completely out of line, although they may not be the perfect solution.

The original form of the question is all but irrelevant. The fact that the asker didn't (or did) realize that the technique e wanted to use wasn't going to work is completely irrelevant, as anything else about eir state of mind would be. The post is now an article on the world web about how to do $WHATEVER. The right thing to do is to make it as easy as possible for people trying to do $WHATEVER to find it now, and conversely to make sure that when they do find it, it's **what they were looking for**.

Best would be both bullets two and three: edit the answer to make the explicit statement "You can't do exactly what you want, but..."; edit the question to make it slightly clearer that when you scroll down, you might not get the CSS solution you were hoping for.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Those are [Spivak pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun).

Comment: I guess I'm the kind of person who prefers keeping as close to the intended question as possible, something that the OP is in the best position to clarify. But I agree there has to be a point where the original point of the question becomes less relevant - ultimately it just has to serve as a basis for the primary source of knowledge - the answer (since, after all, an answer needs to have a question to address).

Comment: @BoltClock: also note that "what the questioner really wants to do" and "what the intended question was" aren't necessarily the same thing, although many answerers assume they are and call it an X-Y problem. I'm sort of resigned to it happening and have mostly given up questioning it, but since you're a mod I'll stick in a word against it. I think it's still legitimate for questioners and future visitors to seek information and do something hopefully-sensible with the answer, not seek someone to redesign their whole app/website/technology stack for them so that the problem goes away ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I never consider the accepted answer as the (single) correct answer. It is just the answer that was most helpful/useful to the OP at that time.

I would leave it as it is or leave a comment to help guide others having the same question.

Answer (score 5):

I have in the past edited questions to match the answers, but only if all the answers match the new question. For example, often the question title is quite general, but all the answers relate to a very specific part of the question or its comments. In that case, I may edit the question title to make it narrower.

If some answers wouldn't match my new edit, then I don't make the edit at all. The new mess wouldn't be better than the old one.

Comment: Editing a question's title to match its body is radically different than editing a question to match an answer.

Comment: @Servy: OK, but I'm talking about a question's title to match its body/comments *as interpreted* by its answers.

Comment: So you don't think that the quesiton's body is asking that question?  If you're going to make that edit then it should be you making the question's title match it's body *as interpreted by you*.  If you don't feel that the interpretation is correct, you shouldn't be making that edit.

Comment: @Servy: I prefer to think in terms of usefulness rather than correctness. If a question has a bunch of answers that were satisfactory but technically not answering the question, this is frustrating for people who choose the question based on the title. Instead of downvoting the answerers, I edit the question to make it match its useful answers, increasing their usefulness. I only do this when all of the answers match the new question, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is fine to edit question to match accepted or well received answer even if edit changes meaning of the question as long as it keeps/improve ability to find the answer by the problem.

Often there are questions that start as some unclear request and than after a lot of comments and random answers actual quite interesting problem surfaces. Answer gets upvotes, maybe even accepted... And than questioner disappears or neglects the question.

Not making an edit to the question to match accepted answer in this case would mean essentially abandoning the work multiple people did as no one will be able to find it later as title usually would be as specific "Problem. Error with String."

I see how such edit performed by original answerer could be considered conflict of interests, but random user should be able to do so. Also if edit is done after comments on the question to update it and some reasonable time like a month I see no problem with even if done by original answerer.

---

Note that this very close to other answer - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283275/477420 but more more about timing of edits on "abandoned" questions.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is quite different from the rest. You emphasize the point about abandoning the work of multiple people, which I wholeheartedly agree with.

Comment: @BoltClock - I've un-deleted it than so people can vote/see.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think it's reasonable to leave things as they are. I'm not an expert in this stuff, but the question says "tricky CSS question, don't know if it's even possible". That reads to me to as requesting some information about CSS.

The answer probably tells you a way to make your page look how you want it to look, but anyone coming along with the same or similar question, ("can this be done in CSS, if so how?") isn't even told it's impossible, let alone any explanation of how we could see that it's impossible.

A downvote means someone thinks the answer is unhelpful, and IMO voters are entitled to judge this in terms of the question actually asked, if they see fit. The fact that the questioner asked the wrong question, and didn't change it when he realised it was wrong, doesn't necessarily mean that the question itself is absurd.

Perhaps the question is absurd, because there's no legit reason to use CSS without jquery. This is where my expertise falls short, I don't know whether or not there are technical reasons or specialist contexts where CSS is used but jquery would impose a significant cost. I suspect so, because I'm a total Luddite who doesn't automatically throw a big framework at every problem ;-p. So I wonder if adding jquery to a page/site solely for this one feature would be overkill, and seeking a CSS-only solution is legitimate.

If the question is absurd, then edit the question, because absurd questions aren't useful to the site or to future visitors. Yes, the answer will have a bunch of misleading downvotes on it, but at least it can now stop gathering more. Stuff happens, not every answer gets the votes it "deserves", especially when question or answer or both are edited at some point. It's not the responsibility of editors to ensure that previously-cast votes remain "correct".

The fact (assuming it's true) that it can't be done in CSS *doesn't* necessarily mean the question is absurd. Not all questions whose answer is "no" are bad questions. If it's legitimate to ask questions about CSS (and if CSS is on-topic for the site), then leave things as they are. The accepted answer helped the questioner, and it will help other future visitors who are asking the wrong question, but it won't help people asking the same question for a legitimate reason. If people think "not helping those asking the same question for a good reason" is enough to downvote, OK.

In extremis, if a question says, "how do I knock a nail in with a hammer, is it possible?" and the answer says, "here's the number of a carpenter", then many people would downvote, and rightly so, even if the questioner found the advice useful and called the carpenter. The only thing distinguishing that case from this case, is people's opinions as to whether it's reasonable to ignore the tool mentioned in the question and suggest a different one instead. Those opinions are (imperfectly, snapshotted at a particular time, subject to their personal biases) reflected in their votes. The voters might all be blithering idiots in some cases, but even so I don't think that edits (still less mods) are there to correct for large numbers of people voting incorrectly. Voting abusively, sure, but being wrong about web technologies not so much.